# calling setter function ruby (see comment after fname=(fname)

Tags: ruby

```
#Creating a class that will count words in any object file
class File_handling
  attr_reader :fname

  def initialize(fname)
    #@fname = fname
    if File.exist? fname
      @fname = fname
    else
      fname=(fname)#why this doesnt work to call the function below
    end
  end

  def fname=(finame)
    if File.exist? finame
      @fname = finame
    else
      p "Enter a good file name >>> "
      filename = gets.chomp
      @fname=(filename)
    end
  end

  def printfile()
    File.foreach(@fname) do |line|
      puts line.chomp
    end
  end
end

f1 = File_handling.new('text.txt')
f1.printfile()

def printfiles(fname)
  File.foreach(fname) do |line|
    puts line
  end
end

p printfiles('test.txt')
```

I'm new to Ruby and trying to understand a few things. I'm not really finished with the class but I would like to know why calling the fname= function above does not work I never get the else message no matter what file name I enter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the interpreter will think you want to assign the value of the local variable `fname` to the local variable `fname`. To make it work, you have to be more explicit:

```
self.fname = fname
```

Comment: Thanks, so let me understand to call setter function I have to use self.[function]. that's a bit different than other languages, but thank you for the quick reply

Comment: @yveskas, in the class itself - yes. Outside, you can call it on the instance at hand. In other languages you often have something like `setVariable` so the compiler/interpreter doesn't get confused if this is local variable assignment or calling a setter.